# Mercurial: Feature branch workflow?

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

Suppose I'm working on a new feature.

While working on my new feature, I get enough basic functionality so that I want to release it while continuing to work on the full feature. When the new feature is fully complete, I want to merge that back to the main release, replacing the basic feature.

What is the Mercurial workflow to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would approach this would be to create a **feature branch**. Mercurial branches can be merged into each other multiple times. So you could merge at milestone 1 (basic / minimal features) and again later (full / complete features) from the feature branch into your main branch.

Branches can be *either named or unnamed / anonymous*; the workflow will work the same either way. Whether you choose to create a named branch is essentially a personal / team preference; be aware that named branches persist forever in the repository history so typically they are used for long-running projects.

Anonymous branches are so common some people don't even realize that's what they are using. Effectively a branch is created anytime you commit work. Each developer will implicitly be working on their own branch (at least until their new work is pushed and synchronized.)  So you could simply work locally on the new feature and only push it to share with others when its ready. Work more, push again later.

Personally I use this approach often because it is very flexible and simple. I often like to keep multiple local repository clones, each dedicated to a single task. These can be easily created, used, and removed at will. If your repository is large then I recommend using `hg share` instead of `hg clone` to create the 2nd through nth local repositories, as it will save time & space.

If you prefer to do so you can also use the Mercurial bookmark feature to "label" an anonymous branch, this could be preferable to creating a permanent named branch since bookmarks can be removed later.